# Calling UIButton:setImage:forState makes button title disappear

Tags: ios, uibutton

If I call `UIButton:setImage:forState` then the title text of my buttons is disappearing (set via `UIButton:setTitle:forState`).

If I don't call `setImage:forState` then the title appears perfectly.

If I set the button images in interface builder then the title does appear, so why does setting the images programmatically cause the titel to vanish?

Comment: What is the size of the image, and what is the size of the button? Setting the image of the button too large can affect the label placement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calling `setImage:forState:`, you should call `setBackgroundImage:forState:`.